# What does the Hecke bound $|a_n| < C n$ say about $\theta(z)^4$?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, sums-of-squares, theta-functions

I am learning modular forms from notes of [Zagier](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.1007/978-3-540-74119-0_1/fulltext.pdf) and I am trying to understand the predictions of the Hecke bound.

> Let $f(z)$ be a cusp form of weight $k$ on $\Gamma$ with Fourier expansion $\sum a_n q^n$.  Then $|a_n| < Cn^{k/2}$ for all $n$ for some constant $C$ depending only on $f$.

Let's test this out on a modular function.  Consider the theta function: $\theta(z) = \sum q^{n^2}$ taking the 4th power:
$$ \theta(z)^4 = \sum r_4(n) q^n $$
where $r_4(n)$ is the number of representation of $n$ as the [sum of 4 squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem).

$\theta(z)^4$ is a modular form of weight 2 on $\Gamma_0(4)$ and the Hecke bound should predict $\boxed{r_4(n) \leq Cn}$ Is this true?

$$ r_4(n) = 8 \sigma(n) - 32 \sigma(n/4) $$
This is taken from Wikipedia and $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of divisors function ([OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000203)) unfortunatly Wikipedia also has that $\frac{1}{n}r_4(n)$ can be arbitrarily large.
$$ \{ n : \frac{r_4(n)}{n} > N \} \neq \varnothing $$
so it looks like the Hecke bound is wrong in this case... or have I misused it?

Comment: That theta is not a cuspform, so the Hecke bound need not hold.

Comment: A probabilistic method predicts that the average number of representations of an integer near $n$ as a sum of four squares is $\pi^2 n$

Comment: @paulgarrett no matter how many times I see the word "cusp form" i don't know what it means.  can you phrase that as an inequality?

Comment: Please see this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_four-square_theorem and this one: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/240002/lower-bound-for-the-number-of-representations-of-integers-as-sum-of-squares

Comment: For things like your theta function that are holomorphic in the upper half-plane variable $z$, they are cuspforms exactly when all the non-positive index exponentials $e^{2\pi inz}$ with $n\le 0$ have coefficients $0$.

Comment: @KhadijaMbarki The 3-sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2 = n$ has surface area $A = 2 \pi n^{3/2}$ and the volume is $V = 4\pi^2 n^2 $ like you said.  I don't know which one to use to estimate, maybe $r_4(n) \leq V$?

Comment: @cactus314 yes you can use it even it is weaker than a probabilistic method but  it is okay since you want just to find a constant $C$ satisfying the inequality mentioned in your question.

Comment: @KhadijaMbarki can you write an answer illustrating probabilistic method?

Comment: @cactus314   Please see this reference (especially page 1 and 2): http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-704-seminar-in-algebra-and-number-theory-rational-points-on-elliptic-curves-fall-2004/projects/lugo.pdf

Comment: @cactus314. From wikipedia.org: A cusp form is distinguished in the case of modular forms for the modular group by the vanishing in the Fourier series expansion (see q-expansion)

    Σ a n q n {\displaystyle \Sigma a_{n}q^{n}} \Sigma a_{n}q^{n}

of the constant coefficient a0.

Comment: @cactus314. This is how I remember the meaning of the "cusp" of the cusp form. From wikipedia.org: A cusp form is distinguished in the case of modular forms for the modular group by the vanishing of the constant coefficient $a_0$ in the Fourier series expansion
$\sum a_{n}q^{n}$... In all cases, though, the limit as q → 0 is the limit in the upper half-plane as $Im(z)\to\infty$ . Taking the quotient by the modular group, say, this limit corresponds to a cusp of a modular curve. So, the definition amounts to saying that a cusp form is a modular form that vanishes at a cusp...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case
$\theta^4(z)$ is a combination of Eisenstein series:
$$\theta^4(z) =  8 E_2(z) - 32 E_2(4z),$$
where
$$E_2(z) := \dfrac{-1}{24} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sigma(n) q^n$$
denotes the "weight $2$ Eisenstein series of level one".
You can think of this as an identity of generating functions that
is equivalent to the formula for $r_4(n)$ in terms of divisor sums.

Actually, $E_2(z)$ is *not* a weight $2$ modular form of level one (which is why I used quotes above); it satisfies a slightly more complicated transformation rule under $z \mapsto -1/z$.  But $E_2^*(z) := E_2(z) - 2 E_2(2z)$ *is*
a weight $2$ modular form on $\Gamma_0(2)$, and so
$E_2^*(z)$ and $E_2^*(2z)$ are weight $2$ modular forms on $\Gamma_0(4)$.
The above identity may then be rewritten as
$$\theta^4(z) = 8 E_2^*(z) + 16 E_2^*(2z),$$
which *is* an equation bewteen weight $2$ modular forms on $\Gamma_0(4)$.

Now you can check that there are *no* cusp forms of weight $2$ on $\Gamma_0(4)$
(e.g. because the modular curve $X_0(4)$ has genus zero), and so the
space of weight $2$ modular forms on $\Gamma_0(4)$ is *spanned* by the Eisenstein series $E_2^*(z)$ and $E_2^*(2z)$.  Thus $\theta^4(z)$ *must* be a linear combination of these two Eisenstein series, and to determine the coefficients, it is enough to compare constant and linear terms in the $q$-expansions.
Thus, just from knowing that $r_4(0) = 1$ and $r_4(1) = 8$, we can *derive* the above formula for $\theta^4(z)$ in terms of Eisenstein series, and thus
*prove* the general formula for $r_4(n)$ in terms of divisor sums.

(My understanding is that this is more-or-less how Jacobi originally proved
this formula.)

However, if we consider $r_{2k}(n)$ for $k > 2$, then we obtain weight $k$ modular forms (on $\Gamma_0(4)$ if $k$ is even, and on $\Gamma_1(4)$ is $k$ is odd).
If $k \leq 4$, then there are no cuspforms of weight $k$, and so we may again write $\theta^{2k}$ as a linear combination of appropriate Eisenstein series,
leading to the standard formulas for $r_{2k}(n)$ in terms of $\sigma_{k-1}(n)$
when $k \leq 4$.  (The case of $8$ squares, i.e. of $k = 4$, is discussed
[here](http://people.math.carleton.ca/~williams/papers/pdf/236.pdf) for example.)

Once $k > 4$, you can't expect $\theta^{2k}$ to be a linear combination of Eisenstein series: rather, it will be a linear combination of Eisentein series, *plus* a cuspform.   This means that $r_{2k}(n)$ will be expressed in terms of $\sigma_{k-1}(n)$, together with the coefficient $a_n$ of a cuspform.

So *now* Hecke's bound is useful: since $\sigma_{k-1}(n)$ grows at
least as rapidly as $n^{k-1}$, we see from Hecke's bound
that $a_n$ can be thought of
as an *error term* in the formula for $r_{2k}(n)$, since $\sigma_{k-1}(n)$ grows at least as rapidly as $n^{k-1}$, while the Hecke bound shows that $a_n$
grows at a slower rate than this.

This is a standard way of estimating $r_{2k}(n)$ (and analogous representation number problems for other quadratic forms) when $k$ is large.